# Changing nticks in subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is the number of ticks on the x and y axes not reduced to 3 in this example?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(nrows=4,ncols=3)
for n in range(0,4):
    for f in range(0,3):
        ax[n,f].plot(range(10), range(10,20))
        ax[n,f].locator_params(axis='x', nticks=3)
        ax[n,f].locator_params(axis='y', nticks=3)

fig.savefig('not_3_ticks.png')
```

I am left with the following figure:[image: not 3 ticks]

Comment: Note that if you omit the axis arg, 'both' is the default value of the axis arg, so you can set both axes with one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `locator_params(axis='x', nticks=3)` is not working as expected is that `nticks` is not a valid argument to the `matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator` in use.

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axes%20axes%20locator_params#matplotlib.axes.Axes.locator_params):

> Typically one might want to reduce the maximum number
>   of ticks and use tight bounds when plotting small
>   subplots, for example::
>
> ```
> ax.locator_params(tight=True, nbins=4)
> ```

So replace `nticks` by `nbins`.

Comment: *is not a valid argument to the matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator* -- A technical point: my reading of the docs is that *any* keyword argument is a valid argument.

Comment: @7stud Sure, any keyword argument can be used, e.g. `ax.locator_params(state_of_mind="excited")` is valid in the sense that it is correctly processed by python. But "valid" here means that it is actually used by the function it gets passed onto.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4,ncols=3)

for n in range(0,4):
    for f in range(0,3):
        ax[n,f].plot(range(10), range(10,20))
        ax[n,f].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))
        ax[n,f].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))

plt.plot()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('yes_3_ticks.png')
```

[image]